# Ninject is reusing instances which are explicitly defined InTransientScope()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject, log4net

I am experiencing an issue, and I have come to a dead end on how to debug and resolve this.

I have an MVC application which is using Ninject for IoC and DI.

One of my dependencies is IApplicationLogger which I am currently implementing using Log4Net.

In my NinjectWebCommon I am binding my IApplicationLogger as follows:

```
kernel.Bind<IApplicationLogger>()
    .ToMethod(ctx =>
    {
        string configFile = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["log4netconfigfilelocation"];
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(new System.IO.FileInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(configFile)));

        var name = ctx.Request.Target.Member.DeclaringType.FullName;

        var log4Netlogger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(name);
        return new Log4NetApplicationLogger(log4Netlogger);
    }).InTransientScope();
```

All fairly straight forward stuff.

However, I am finding that the first instance of IApplicationLogger which is activated is then passed to all constructors which require an IApplicationLogger instance.

for example I have the following

```
 public class A : IA
 {
        public A(IB bclass, IC cclass, IApplicationLogger logger){}
    }

public class B : IB
{
    public B(IApplicationLogger logger){}
}

public class C : IC
{
    public C(IApplicationLogger logger){}
}
```

I have set breakpoints on each constructor and also the line in my NinjectWebCommon kernel.Bind().ToMethod(ctx =>

What I see is this:

- Break point in NinjectWebCommon is hit, and I can see
  ctx.Request.Target.Member.DeclaringType.FullName is Class B.
- Break point in Constructor Class B is hit and logger
  instance is correct
- Break point in Constructor Class C is hit, and
  logger instance has a logger name of Type Class B
- Break point in Constructor Class A is hit, and logger instance has a logger 
  name of Class B

I would expect the breakpoint within NinjectWebCommon to be hit for each new instance of IApplicationLogger that is required, but it is only hit once for the first activation for the instance of Class B.

I have tried my Binding without the InTransientScope() option.

My IA, IB and IC bindings are defined InSingletonScope().  This shouldn't cause an issue as I am expecting Ninject to activate an instance of each, each with it's own instance of IApplicationLogger.

The result of the binding I am seeing currently is that logging statements I output in say Class A are being recorded in the Log as being from a logger name for class of type B.

Can anyone suggest how I can diagnose why Ninject is reusing the TransientScoped() IApplicationLogger, or how I can peek under the hood of what Ninject is doing so that I can analyse this in greater detail?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested I didn't discover the underlying issue here, but I have opted to inject an ILoggerFactory with a single method .GetLogger(string typename), allowing my classes to request their own Logger and passing their own Type name.

This way I can ensure that each Class has it's own logger, with the LoggerName matching the Class TypeName.